Why is the Jacobi amplitude real when $k>1$?
I understand the Jacobi amplitude is defined as the inverse function of the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind
$$
\mathrm{am}(u,k) = F^{-1}(u,k),
$$
where
$$
F(u,k) = \int_0^u \frac{d\phi}{1-k^2\sin(\phi)^2},
$$
is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind. But if $F(u,k)$ has an imaginary part for every real $u>\arcsin(\frac{1}{k})$, how can the amplitude $\mathrm{am}(u,k)$ be real for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$, and especially, how can $\mathrm{am}(u,k)$ be real when $\arcsin(\frac{1}{k})<u<\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Simply, because the substitution $1-k^2 \sin^2 \phi \mapsto 1 - \sin^2 \phi'$  for $k>1$ yields the elliptic $F(\theta, \frac{1}{k} )$.
The inverse is an oscillating function as as solutions of $$\ddot \phi = -\sin\phi$$ for the swinging pendulum, that conventionally can be expressed by an inverse trigonometric function of a scaled Jacobi elliptic function.
Instead of the formula for the rotating pendulum $k<1$
$$ am(\phi,k) = \sin^{-1} sn(\phi,k )$$
you will get something like
$$ am(\phi,\frac{1}{k}) = a \ \sin^{-1}  (b \ \text{sd} ( c  \phi,\frac{1}{k} )$$ with $s\text{d}=\frac{\text{sn}}{\text{dn}}$
Since $am(\phi,k<1)$ is not elliptic (its derivative $\text{dn}$ is elliptic), the value in the complex plane with a lattice of poles depends on the path of integration of $\text {dn}$.
Numerics differ by implementation. While e.g. in Mathematica  $\text{am}(t,k>1)$ was a real periodic function, in the newest versions it makes jumps by $4\pi$ per period.
The background is the fact, the the pendulum velocity dn-function oscillates with positive values for $k<1$ in rotational mode, but becomes a sinusoidal oscillating cn-function for k>1.
$$\text{Series}\left[\text{dn}\left(x\left|\frac{1}{k^2}\right.\right)-\text{cn}\left(\frac{x}{k}|k^2\right),\{x,0,7\}\right]=O\left(x^8\right)$$ in Mathematica with quadratic modulus as parameter.

thanks Roland that very useful, i'm going to take some time to check what you shared but i'm pretty sure you answered all my points
